# Execute 'Form_Shown' event handler more than once?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, event-handling

I am currently developing a Windows app with several forms. I use `Form_Shown` in one of those forms to execute some code to initialize (refresh) the form before showing it.

In [Form.Shown Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.shown.aspx) on MSDN, it states that the event is raised  *only the first time* the form is shown. However, I want to be able to execute code to initialize my form *every time* that I call `Form.Show()` in some of the forms. Here's an example.

1. From a form named `Game`. Contains an event handler `Game_Shown` and a button that when clicked shows a form named `Menu`:

   ```
   private void btnMenu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       this.Hide();
       Formulaires.formMenu.Show();
   }

   private void Game_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       Code here...
       this.Refresh();
   }
   ```
2. From the form named `Menu`. Contains a button that when clicked shows the form named `Game`:

   ```
   private void lblGame_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       this.Hide();
       Formulaires.formGame.Show();
   }
   ```

Comment: Have you actually tried it? The shown event will execute for each new instance of the Form. If you are showing/hiding 1 instance you need another event.

Comment: I tried it and it actually works only the first time, your answers don't help since I do Show/Hides in my program, I load it only once...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is behaving by design.

From the docs:
    The Shown  event occurs whenever the form is **first** shown.

Also, you should not handle the Shown event in your class, rather you should override OnShown.

To achieve what you want, you might try overriding the OnVisibleChanged method.  Inside the method, if the form is visible, then execute your code.

Like the Shown event, you should not handle it in your form class, instead override the appropriate method:

From the docs:
The OnVisibleChanged method also allows derived classes to handle the event without attaching a delegate. This is the preferred technique for handling the event in a derived class.

Answer (score 2):

What you want requires some detailed knowledge about which event happens when in the WinForm lifecycle. That may be documented somewhere, I don't know.

This is how I would find out:

1. create a small test project with 2 forms (Main and helper)
2. add the show and hide buttons and make sure it works.
3. Add `Debug.Print("EventName")` to all the candidate events of the helper form.
4. Look at the log in the output window and pick your event.

Candidate events would be FormClosing, FormClosed, (De)Activated, Enter, Leave, Load, ... go through the list.

When you find the right one, please post it here in an answer.

Comment: Well, I didn't want to go through all this but I think that it is the only way to be sure of what is done. thanks for help though +1

Comment: Regarding "which event happens when," see [Order of Events in Windows Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86faxx0d.aspx).